# Using JNA to access a struct containing an array of structs

Tags: arrays, struct, jna

I have a C library that uses a struct which contains an array of another struct. I am having some difficulty determining the correct way to access this from Java via JNA.

The C code is as follows:

```
typedef struct Item {
    int x;
} Item;
typedef struct ItemList {
    int itemCount;
    Item* items; // an array of Item
} ItemList;

int addItemList(ItemList list)
{
    int result = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i=0; i<list.itemCount; i++)
    {
        result += (list.items)[i].x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am able to work with this from a C application with the following example:

```
ItemList list;
list.itemCount = 3;
list.items = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item) * 3);
list.items[0].x = 1;
list.items[1].x = 2;
list.items[2].x = 3;
int y = addItemList(list);
printf("%d\n", y);
```

I have tried to access this from Java (via JNA) with the following Java code:

```
public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    public static class Item extends Structure {
        public static class ByValue extends Item implements Structure.ByValue {}
        public int x;
    }
    public static class ItemList extends Structure {
        public static class ByValue extends ItemList implements Structure.ByValue {}
        public static class ByReference extends ItemList implements Structure.ByReference {}
        public int itemCount;
        public Item[] items;
    }
    int addItemList(ItemList.ByValue items);
}

...

CLibrary.Item[] items = (CLibrary.Item[])new CLibrary.Item().toArray(3);
items[0].x = 1;
items[1].x = 2;
items[2].x = 3;
CLibrary.ItemList.ByValue list = new CLibrary.ItemList.ByValue();
list.items = items;
list.itemCount = 3;
int y = clib.addItemList(list);
System.out.println(y);
```

However, the above Java leads to a core dump.

I tried changing the ItemList definition (in Java) to use an array of Item.ByValue:

```
public static class ItemList extends Structure {
    public static class ByValue extends ItemList implements Structure.ByValue {}
    public static class ByReference extends ItemList implements Structure.ByReference {}
    public int itemCount;
    public Item.ByValue[] items;
}
```

and then changed the usage (in Java) to:

```
CLibrary.Item.ByValue[] items = (CLibrary.Item.ByValue[])new CLibrary.Item.ByValue().toArray(3);
items[0].x = 1;
items[1].x = 2;
items[2].x = 3;
CLibrary.ItemList.ByValue list = new CLibrary.ItemList.ByValue();
list.items = items;
list.itemCount = 3;
int y = clib.addItemList(list);
```

but with the same result.

I have also tried changing the C function signature to

```
int addItemList(ItemList* list);
```

and adjusted the C implementation accordingly. Then I changed the Java code to pass a CLibrary.ItemList.ByReference to addItemList - but with the same results.

What am I missing? What is the appropriate way to pass a struct containing an array of structs from Java to C using JNA?

Comment: Your struct does not contain an array of struct, but rather a pointer to that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work with the original C code by using the following Java code:

```
public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    public static class Item extends Structure {
        public static class ByReference extends Item implements Structure.ByReference {}
        public int x;
    }
    public static class ItemList extends Structure {
        public static class ByValue extends ItemList implements Structure.ByValue {}
        public int itemCount;
        public Item.ByReference items;
    }
    int addItemList(ItemList.ByValue items);
}

…

CLibrary.ItemList.ByValue list = new CLibrary.ItemList.ByValue();
list.items = new CLibrary.Item.ByReference();
list.itemCount = 3;
CLibrary.Item[] items = (CLibrary.Item[])list.items.toArray(3);
items[0].x = 1;
items[1].x = 2;
items[2].x = 3;
int y = clib.addItemList(list);
System.out.println(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

As I see on top you've got a problem.

On top of your code, you were using `Item.ByValue` on 
*Item**

But it should be `Item.ByReference`.